# Decode personalizado para JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json

Tengo una clase :

```
class NodoArbolDHTML{
    var $id;
    var $name;
    var $data;
    var $children;


    public function __construct($id,$name,$resultado,$tipo){
       $this->id = $id;
       $this->name = $name;
       $this->data = new datos($resultado,$tipo);

    }

    public function anadirHijo($nodoHijo, $id){   
        //anadir un hijo
       if (!isset($this->children)){
          $this->children = array();
       }
       $this->children[$id] = $nodoHijo;
       $this->children = array_values($this->children);

    }
 }
```

Con la que puedo crear un objeto de éste tipo:

```
$root= NodoArbolDHTML Object ( 
  [id] => 38358 
  [name] => Anillo Critico 
  [data] => datos Object ( [color] => #008000 [type] => circle ) 
  [children] => Array ( 
    [0] => NodoArbolDHTML Object ( 
            [id] => 38347 
            [name] => Transito 
            [data] => datos Object ( [color] => #008000 [type] => circle ) 
            [children] => 
          )
    [1] => NodoArbolDHTML Object ( 
            [id] => 43052 
            [name] => Centros de Acceso 
            [data] => datos Object ( [color] => #008000 [type] => circle ) 
            [children] => 
          ) 
  ) 
)
```

Y puedo acceder a un objeto de los del array :

```
print_r($root->children[0]); :

NodoArbolDHTML Object ( 
      [id] => 38347  
      [name] => Transito 
      [data] => datos Object ( 
                   [color] => #008000 
                   [type] => circle 
                ) 
      [children] => 
)
```

Luego hago un `$arbol=json_encode($root)` y obtengo un objeto en notación JSON:

```
// $arbol
{
    "id": "38358",
    "name": "Anillo Critico",
    "data": {
        "$color": "#008000",
        "$type": "circle"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "38347",
            "name": "Transito",
            "data": {
                "$color": "#008000",
                "$type": "circle"
            },
            "children": null
        },
        {
            "id": "43052",
            "name": "Centros de Acceso",
            "data": {
                "$color": "#008000",
                "$type": "circle"
            },
            "children": null
        }
    ]
}
```

necesito una función dentro de la clase `NodoArbolDHTML` que haga el proceso inverso, a la que yo le dé el JSON en notación JSON.

De éste modo , podría:

- usar la función anadirHijo
- Recorrer el array , buscando el objeto que me interese :

  ```
  print_r($root->children[0]);

  NodoArbolDHTML Object ( 
      [id] => 38347 
      [name] => Transito 
      [data] => datos Object ( [color] => #008000 [type] => circle ) 
      [children] => 
  )
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible realizar con las funciones propias de PHP, por lo que debes utilizar alguna solución custom. En el siguiente [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397758/json-decode-to-custom-class) hay una solución a tu problemática en SO en inglés.

Específicamente para tu problema:

```
class NodoArbolDHTML {
    [...]

    public static function fromJSONObject($jsonObject) {
        $nodo = new NodoArbolDHTML($jsonObject->id, $jsonObject->name, $jsonObject->resultado, $jsonObject->tipo);

        if(count($jsonObject->children) > 0) {
          foreach($jsonObject->children as $child) {
            $nodo->anadirHijo(NodoArbolDHTML::fromJSONObject($child), $child->id);
          }
        }

        return $nodo;
    }
}

$arbol = NodoArbolDHTML::fromJSONObject(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, lo primero muchísimas gracias.En un tiempo record!

Comment: Mira, sólo un detalle, que será una tontería pero llevo ya un rato bueno.Lo he ejecutado asI:

Comment: Pablo , me sale esto: [Thu Aug 18 15:06:06 2016] [error] [client 10.32.153.159] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /APRMARA/home/proactiv/Desarrollo/web/mapas/prueba3.php on line 72

Comment: @Mayte  actualicé el codigo

Comment: @Mayte si esto soluciona tu problema, marcas como resuelto? :D

Comment: Gracias!!! Gracias!!! Gracias!!! Resueltísimo!!!

Comment: Pablo , llevo ya un buen rato buscando cómo marcar la pregunta como resuelta y no lo encuentro. ¿cómo se hace esto?

Comment: @Mayte me aparece como que ya está ok. Gracias ;)